# How to implement mbtowc for android? (or, ideally, how not to?)

Tags: android, c, boost, android-ndk, arm

I am attempting to build an Android app that makes use of boost serialization. I have built the library against NDK r8d using arm 4.7's g++. When I go to compile my native code into a library using ndk-build, however, I get  "undefined reference to 'mbtowc'" and "undefined reference to 'wctomb'" when the compiler attempts to link some code from Archive headers in boost.

I cannot seem to get a clear answer as to whether the NDK supports these functions.

Although it implements the functions, the CrystaX NDK is not an option as it has known crashes when using it with Boost, according to the Boost mailing list.

So, if the NDK does implement these functions somehow, why is NDK-build unable to link against them? I can find reference to them in cstdlib within the NDK, and I believe there may be a flag I need to set, but I'm not sure how or where to do so.

If there is no implementation of them, does anyone have any advice on how I can write them myself? I know roughly what mbtowc and its complement are supposed to do, but without much experience writing low-level C, and without much knowledge of Android / ARM architecture, I could really use some advice on doing so.

Comment: One incredibly lame option would be to call back to Java. Another would be linking to `libiconv`.It might be worth it to dig in Android sources and see what library does Java itself use. Reimplementing codepage conversion from scratch is not something one should casually endeavor to.

Comment: You can simply grep through the NDK headers to check function availability. I'm curious about your statement about CrystaX NDK and Boost? We've been using it for many years now.

Comment: Have you been using it with the Serialization library? That's the one that I need, which requires wchar support by default that isn't present on Android. It's unfortunate that there are too many such variables to explicitly state anywhere which libraries will work on different platforms, or to make boost's compatibility all-or-nothing.

It appears there are preprocessor definitions that will configure boost to build with the assumption that wchars aren't supported on the target platform. I have run into other issues trying to test that approach. I'll post my findings when I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Findings! Yes, boost has options to build it without requiring wchar support by adding preprocessor definitions to the boost build scripts. Boost still crashes when built using them at the line of code where I attempt to serialize an object to file. (the crash is a generic segfault at 0x00000000, and I was unable to gain any useful information).

So, I haven't bothered writing wctomb or its inverse. I shouldn't need to, is the answer to my question, although in the end the answer to the question doesn't matter.

To further clarify: don't bother doing what I've been trying to do. If you have been using Boost's serialization library and want your code to run on android ndk r8d or earlier, just give up. Write a serializer yourself, because there is no useful information to be found on how to make Serialization work. Hopefully a future release of the ndk fixes this problem, but for now I have no choice but to just rewrite everything.

Answer (score 9):

```
#ifdef ANDROID
int wctomb(char *s, wchar_t wc) { return wcrtomb(s,wc,NULL); }
int mbtowc(wchar_t *pwc, const char *s, size_t n) { return mbrtowc(pwc, s, n, NULL); }
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was creating an android port for code that uses boost::serialization.

My code failed to compile because of missing implementation of `mbtowc` / `wctomb` (mb: multi-byte (char), wc: (wide-char)'

Implementation of these functions will probably be tricky cause as far as I know the wide-char for android is a single byte char instead of a true wide character..

However when I compiled boost with `-DBOOST_NO_STD_WSTRING` the link errors disappeared and I could use `boost::archive::text_iarchive` & `boost::archive::text_oarchive` on android.

I am now serializing STL containers of numerics and std::strings without a problem.

I compiled boost for android following the advice on this link: http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2011/05/tips-tricks-building-boost-with-ndk-r5/

I am using boost-1.55_0 and NDK r9c.

I added the following  `<compileflags>-DBOOST_NO_STD_WSTRING` to the build command so it would build serialization library without wide character support.